# How to copy XML nodes from a text file and paste it as a EMF EObject in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, clipboard, emf

I have a text file which contains multiple XML nodes. I want each node to be copied/converted as an EMF Object and be pasted in the eclipse editor (by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in text file and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in the eclipse editor). But I am not able to paste in the Eclipse editor. Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question. You can read your XML model and convert it into an XMI model. In that way you need to implement the next code into your EMF Project. I created a new class and I generate a main method including this code:

```
    //Generate your URI
    ResourceFactoryImpl factory = new ResourceFactoryImpl();
    URI sourceURI = URI.createURI("your xml path");
    Resource loadResource = (ResourceImpl)factory.createResource(sourceURI);
    System.out.println(sourceURI.path());

    //Add loading options
    Map<String, Boolean> options = new HashMap<String, Boolean>(); 
    options.put(XMLResource.OPTION_SUPPRESS_DOCUMENT_ROOT, true);

    //Load XML
    loadResource.load( options);

    //Create XMI output
    URI targetURI = URI.createURI("your xmi path");
    Resource resourceOut = new ResourceImpl(targetURI);

    //Generating your EObjects from XML model
    EList listObj = loadResource.getContents();
    EObject obj = (EObject) listObj.get(0);
    resourceOut.getContents().add(obj);

    resourceOut.save(options);
```

Remember that you need to register your EPackages from your ecore model. So, right click your .ecore metamodel and select the option "Register EPackages". If there is a problem with this step you are going to obtain a org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource$IOWrappedException: Package with uri 'http://something.com' not found. (xml path).

In conclusion:

1. Invoke a method into your main method tha includes the presented
   code.
2. Register your EPackages.
3. If you obtain an Exception resolve URI data into XML.

PD: The code presented on this post was initially created by @victormpav. I add some modifications.